# how to allow end user to input value in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

My sql server code is:

```
Create Function [dbo].[FunTest]
(

)
Returns Table
As
Return
(
   select * from persons where Id = '&Id' 
)
```

How can I allow end user to input value (`@Id`) to tabled-function like show dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your parameter to your function:

```
Create Function [dbo].[FunTest]
(
   @id int
)
Returns Table
As
Return
(
   select * from persons where Id = @id 
)
```

As for prompting the user like a dialog: not in SQL! You'll have to knock up a front-end for that (e.g. report)

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want to show dialog for end user to input the id value.

Comment: @neo-ray You can't do that in SQL-land. You will **have** to use another technology.